# chaining ifelse with mutate not working

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks something like:

```
placeID <- c(001, 002, 003, 004, 005)
faultDscr <- c("6940 broken", "6122 not working", "6122 broken", "6940 not working", "printer not working")
partID <- c("PTR-HP-6940", NA, "PTR-HP-6122", NA, NA)
myData <- data.frame(placeID, faultDscr, partID)
```

I want to create a new variable to identify if a site is using a 6122 inkjet as part of my dplyr pipeline.  The new variable should contain either a Y or an N.  I have used the code below:

```
library(dplyr)
inkjetSites <- myData %>%
mutate(inkjetSite = ifelse(partID == "PTR-HP-6122", "Y",
                             ifelse(is.na(partID) && grep("6122", faultDscr), "Y", "N")))
```

I'd hoped to get an output like:

```
inkjetSite <- c("N", "Y", "Y", "N", "N")
inkjetSitesCor <- data.frame(placeID, faultDscr, partID, inkjetSite)
```

However I instead got an output like:

```
inkjetSite <- c("N", NA, "Y", NA, NA)
inkjetSitesInCor <- data.frame(placeID, faultDscr, partID, inkjetSite)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try with `%in%` and remove the `==` as the NA will remain as NA there (unless we create an `& !is.na(partID)`), change the `&&` to `&` and also change from `grep` to `grepl` (for logical vector output)

```
myData %>% 
     mutate(inkjetSite = ifelse(partID %in% "PTR-HP-6122", "Y", 
              ifelse(is.na(partID) & grepl("6122", faultDscr), "Y", "N")))
#  placeID           faultDscr      partID inkjetSite
#1       1         6940 broken PTR-HP-6940          N
#2       2    6122 not working        <NA>          Y
#3       3         6122 broken PTR-HP-6122          Y
#4       4    6940 not working        <NA>          N
#5       5 printer not working        <NA>          N
```

---

This can be also done without an `ifelse`

```
myData %>%
   mutate(inkjetSite =  c("N", "Y")[partID %in% "PTR-HP-6122" + 
              (is.na(partID) & grepl("6122", faultDscr)) + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using case_when

```
mutate(inkjetSite = case_when(is.na(partID) ~ 'N',
                                                  partID == "PTR-HP-6122" ~ "Y",
                                                  grepl('6122', faultDscr) ~ 'Y', 
                                                  TRUE ~ 'N'))
```

And you should test if partID is NA *before* checking its value.